# What is the purpose of the < (less than symbol) before path in dovecot settings

Tags: dovecot

In the default dovecot ssl config file the certificate file paths are specified like:

```
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
```

What is the purpose of that `<` symbol preceding the path?

**UPDATE:** A comment below contained a dead link to docs detailing this syntax. Here is the current working link which may be helpful to future readers: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/config_file/#reading-value-from-file

Comment: [Link to documentation](https://wiki.dovecot.org/ConfigFile#Reading_value_from_file)

Comment: thanks - i looked for an explanation in the docs but failed to find it.  appreciate the link.  it's also good to know that the settings are read when the service is loaded

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s to make it read the contents of the file rather than using the literal string `“/etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem”` as the certificate.

Comment: I see - so it's a redirection operator.  I was speculating about that but just seems odd to use it this way in a config file.